# How to disable default apps in Laragon

Tags: apache, laravel, laragon

I have installed Laragon; after hearing so much about it. The feature of note here is its ability to create named aliases on the fly when you a new folder is in `DOCUMENT_ROOT` i.e. if a new folder *testapp*, a new domain *testapp.dev* is created on the next restart of Laragon's web server.

Laragon ships with some four default apps

1. Laragon: for file uploads
2. PHPMyAdmin
3. PHPRedisAdmin
4. Memcached

These are cool when accessed via localhost for administrative purposes. However, turns out these apps can also be accessed via the apps created i.e. *testapp.dev/phpmyadmin* brings you to Laragon's default PHPMyAdmin.

How do I turn this off for sites I have under Laragon? How do I make these apps only accessible via localhost?

**EDIT:**
I have gone into the alias folder and commented out the lines for each laragon app

```
Alias /laragon-app /path/to/laragon-app
```

But this *obviously* makes the app inaccessible since Apache no longer serves it. So requests to `http://localhost/laragon-app` returns a 404

Answer (score 2):

Just rename alias folder to another name and reload Apache.
The structure like below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FieUd.png

Comment: I tried this and Laragon's Apache wouldn't start because it's looking for `alias/laragon.conf`

Comment: You can keep the alias folder and Right click to open Menu > Apache > httpd.conf, go to the end of the file, comment the Include ... <IfModule alias_module>
# Include "C:/laragon/alias/*"
</IfModule>